# Администратор Django может удалить себя

Tags: django, django-admin

Две связанные задачи:

- суперпользователь Django не должен иметь возможности удалить себя;
- суперпользователь не должен иметь возможность отключить свои
  привилегии.

Answer (score 0):

Решение сделал, но не уверен, что лучшим образом, странно, что не могу найти готового решения. Предложения приветствуются.

admin.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.unregister(User)

@admin.register(User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',)}),
    )
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.id == request.user.id and request.user.is_superuser:
            obj.is_superuser = True
            obj.is_active = True
            obj.is_staff = True
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return (request.user.id != obj.id) if obj else True
```

Таким образом скрыты группы пользователей, доступ к разным типам контента, администратор не может удалить себя и видит поля ['is_superuser', 'is_active', 'is_staff'], может изменять их для других, но не может сохранить отключение прав для себя.